# Arduino Uno unable to detect usb port on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, ftdi, mac-os

Few weeks ago my Arduino Uno (IDE version 1.8.2) detected the USB port and I was able to do some small IOT projects. I updated my OS to Sierra 10.12.5 and now suddenly the usb serial option has disappeared.

[image]

I followed this link : https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/mac  where it tells us to download and install the FTDI drivers separately. I tried that but it did not help.

Then I came across this post: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=427825.0 where the user is having this same problem with MacOS Sierra. He suggested we remove the FTDI drivers and rely on Apple's drivers. So I removed the FTDI drivers from my Mac so it will use Apple's drivers.

Now even after doing all this when I connect my Arduino Uno to my Mac via the USB it does not get detected.

I removed the kext and pkg files for the FTDI drivers and deleted them completely, still when I open the System Report I still see the FTDI USB Serial Driver entry.

[image]

When I go to System Report > Hardware > USB I see this:

[image]

What is happening? Did the FTDI drivers got removed? If they did then why wont the serial usb port get detected on Arduino? If they are not removed completely then what did I miss?

Comment: If you have a genuine Arduino you don't want the FTDI drivers. There hasn't been an FTDI on an Arduino for many years. If you have a cheap Chinese clone then you probably want the CG340G drivers (and good luck with those). Genuine Arduino boards use a CDC/ACM interface, and all modern operating systems have those drivers built in.

Comment: I am not sure if my Arduino is genuine or cheap chinese knockoff. I got it off from Amazon as a part of IOT starter kit. It worked properly in the beginning and as I mentioned I did some projects on it.

Comment: Unless you went through the rigmarole of installing the CG340G drivers (and you'd remember doing that, trust me) then it's probably *like* a genuine Arduino (with an ATMega16U2 chip as the USB interface) - however, is it actually genuine? Only a picture of the board could tell us that (there's telltale signs you can see if you know what you're looking for). If it's not genuine then it could be that the USB interface chip is dead (it may be a cloned chip or a factory reject).

Comment: Found this on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyocdvAKo64&t=0s   what do you think?

Comment: That's for cheap chinese clones only - CH340G. Post a picture of your board please.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B43t-lgy1BmXUHZ2cWJFdHZpSWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's what we in the trade call counterfeit: it's pretending to be a genuine Arduino but isn't. Clues: there's no TM on the Arduino logo. They misspelled "RESET EN" calling it "RESET CN" instead. The silk screen isn't of a high enough quality. There's no "WWW.ARDUINO.CC - MADE IN ITALY" on the front. The font isn't quite right (too angular). So there is a chance the ATMega16U2 chip has died. I don't use a mac though so can't offer diagnostic suggestions.

Comment: So does this mean that the complete Arduino is useless? I have to buy a new one?

Comment: Not necessarily. As I say I don't use mac, so I can't help you diagnose it. There may be some other cause. If it is the ATMega16U2 though you can bypass it with a cheap USB to UART TTL adaptor connected to pins 0/1 and DTR to RESET through a 100nF capacitor. Just as if it were an ATMega328P on a breadboard.

Comment: Ok. Nevermind it worked. I followed the YouTube video I shared above and now the board is detected. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Strange that, since it doesn't use that driver. However it may kick the USB subsystem into action I guess as a side-effect.

Comment: I followed this you Tube Vedieo : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyocdvAKo64&t=0s and I installed the CH340 driver but I do not found the more than ports in port option [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXU0g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXU0g.png) but I still did't get my serial port [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOcrN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOcrN.png)

Comment: For me Peba's answer here helped me https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/forum.topic.topic.15.15.html/cp120x_vcp_driverno-G1Bu

Answer (score 2):

I installed the CH340 Driver and the board now shows the USB serial as port option: https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver

Comment: This *cannot* be an answer to the question asked, as the Uno does not have a CH340.   **Either the *question* or the answer is incorrect**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am fairly new to IOT and electronics in general. I did what I could to find a solution to my problem and it worked. If you are so enlightened in this matter then please feel free to give a "correct" solution to my problem or "correct" the questions.

Comment: I had the same problem w/ an Arduino Uno after upgrading to Sierra--no issue with USB port detection before upgrade and issue afterwards. I downloaded and installed the driver from the said github repo and then after reboot, it worked! Thanks for offering this solution.

Comment: Hi, You have to install CoolTerm for mac. http://freeware.the-meiers.org/